# Accidentally wrote over the wrong partition

Tags: linux, partitioning, data-recovery

When doing an install of Linux Mint, I accidentally installed on a partition that already had data on it, so now that partition has a clean install of Mint instead of the data that was there before.

I was hoping that I could at least recover *some* of the data from this partition, so my questions would be what, if anything, could I recover, and how would I go about doing that?

Comment: There are several programs that allow for erased data recovery, dont know how well it would work on an entire partition though. But I would recommend not booting into that partition until you do any recovery.  It might work best to take out the drive and open the program and drive on a different machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As (a sandwhich) has mentioned, you probably don't want to boot into that partition. Instead, try a bootable image (CD/DVD or USB) such as the Ubuntu Rescue Remix[1]. They recommend various things to try[2] -- I've personally had some luck creating an image (onto another USB HDD) with ddrescue, then running foremost to recover particular file-types.

Hope that helps!

[1] http://ubuntu-rescue-remix.org/

[2] https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery

Comment: I unfortunately booted into the partition before I discovered the problem, but I've been able to recover *some* stuff. Only problem is that I seriously lack hard drive space and money.

Answer (score 0):

If your data is important enough to justify the cost ($500-$10,000 depending on time and difficulty) you can send it to a professional recovery service like  [DriveSavers](http://www.drivesaversdatarecovery.com)

Otherwise, you can try your hand at [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk), though results are never guaranteed.

Comment: I wish I had that kind of money, but alas...